# Get Users with params and without others

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to get group's users with specific ids that are not admin.

For the moment I have:

```
group.users
     .joins(:roles)
     .where(id: user_ids)
     .where.not(roles: { role_type: Role::Type::ADMIN })
     .pluck(:id)
```

In my log I have:

SQL to load the `group`:

```
  (0.3ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "groups_users" 
  ON "users"."id" = "groups_users"."user_id" 
  WHERE "groups_users"."group_id" = $1  [["group_id", 137375]]
```

SQL for the query above:

```
  (0.6ms)  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "roles" 
  ON "roles"."user_id" = "users"."id" AND "roles"."is_destroyed" = $1 
  INNER JOIN "groups_users" ON "users"."id" = "groups_users"."user_id"
  WHERE "groups_users"."group_id" = $2 AND "users"."id" IN (82884, 82885)
  AND "roles"."role_type" != $3  [["is_destroyed", "f"],
  ["group_id", 137375], ["role_type", 1]]
```

The problem is I always get all the users of the group with matching `user_ids`. The `where.not` is not effective.

I had to do something like

```
users_in_group  = group.users.where(id: user_ids).pluck(:id) 

users_in_group -= group.users.joins(:roles).where
                 (roles: { role_type: Role::Type::ADMIN}).pluck(:id)
```

I don't understand why.

Comment: What is the value of `Role::Type::ADMIN`?

Comment: This is most likely because users have multiple roles. An Admin user is probably having other roles too.

Comment: You're true @Humza !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude Admins even if they have other roles, you might use SQL `EXISTS`:

```
group.users
     .where(id: user_ids)
     .where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM roles WHERE user_id = users.id AND role_type = ?", Role::Type::ADMIN)
     .pluck(:id)
```

And, handling typical objection to such advice: it's *perfectly fine* to get your hands dirty by writing fragments of SQL when you are using ActiveRecord in Rails. You shouldn't limit yourself to the (not so broad) possibilities of its DSL.

**UPD**.

To simplify your code, you can use [Where Exists](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) gem (disclosure: I've written it recently).

Add `gem 'where_exists'` to your Gemfile, run `bundle install`, and then the following should work:

```
group.users
     .where(id: user_ids)
     .where_not_exists(:roles, role_type: Role::Type::ADMIN)
     .pluck(:id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I've properly understand your comment. You mean I should not use fragment of sql like the one you wrote ? But in this case it's the only solution ?

Comment: No, I mean you should use them whenever you find them useful. And this is one of the cases.

Comment: @BeniMio I've updated my answer, written a gem to simplify such queries. Also added another answer to your another question with similar task :)